# Unit Test URL with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

The method below checks if a GET request to a specified URL returns a given response.

```
public class URLHealthCheck extends HealthCheck {
    private URL url;
    private int expectedResponse = 0;

    public URLHealthCheck(String description) {
        setType("urlcheck");
        setDescription(description);
    }

    public Result run() {
        Result result = Result.Fail;
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == expectedResponse) {
                result = Result.Pass;
            } else {
                setMessage("Expected HTTP code " + expectedResponse + " but received " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        }
        setResult(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

To test this method I wrote the following test:

```
class UrlHealthCheckTest {
    private URLHealthCheck healthCheck;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        healthCheck = new URLHealthCheck("Test URL");
    }


    @Test
    void testMockUrl() throws IOException {
        URL url = mock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        when(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);
        when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(httpURLConnection);
        healthCheck.setUrl(url);
        healthCheck.setExpectedResponse(200);
        Result result = healthCheck.run();
        assertTrue(result == Result.Pass);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this unit test does not fully test the method under test `run()` Specifically, it does not test these lines

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
```

Initially, I had a test that used an existing website, eg, https://www.google.com, but it was dependent on an internet connection. What is a better way to test this method?

Comment: what does Result result  = getFailType(); do?

Comment: @SACHESHAC Its not really important. I changed the code to represent what it returns, which is just a value from an enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if your mocked entity has an expected state or performed certain behaviour.

```
Result result = healthCheck.run();

//Verify if `connect` was called exactly once
Mockito.verify(httpURLConnection, Mockito.times(1)).connect(); 

//Verify if a correct Http Method was set
assertEquals("GET", connection.getRequestMethod());
```

Comment: Would you put the additional verify/assert in the same test method or split them up?

Comment: ideally in the same method

Comment: In the line `assertEquals("GET", connection.getRequestMethod());`, `getRequestMethod()` always returns null. Is it because I'm returning result and not HttpURLConnectoin?